# Jquery Datatable sorting error with date

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, datatable

We have an issue where we have a table with 7 columns and if we sort on multiple columns in IE 7 where the first sort column is a string and the second sort column is a Date, the paging stops working. In FireFox we get the error: 'q[d + ("-" + k[f][1])]' is not a function. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-asc'] = function (a, b) {
            var x = new Date(a),
             y = new Date(b);
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        };

        jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['us_date-desc'] = function (a, b) {
            var x = new Date(a),
             y = new Date(b);
            return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
        };

        $('.tbl').dataTable({
            'bFilter': false,
            'bSort': true,
            'bLengthChange': false,
            'sPaginationType': 'two_button',
            'bRetrieve': true,
            'iDisplayLength': 25,
            'aaSorting': [[6, 'asc'], [0, 'asc']],
            'aoColumns': [{ "sType": 'us_date-asc' }, null, null, null, null, null, null]
            //We also tried using this:   'aoColumns': [{ "sType": "date" }, null, null, null, null, null, null]


        });

    });
```

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle or jsbin example?

Comment: do you have sample data? the date sType uses the javascript Date() object, which your data might not match.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the first object in aoColumns to only the property name like this?

```
'aoColumns': [{ "sType": 'us_date' }, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `'date'` unless you have the Date (dd/mm/yy) plugin installed.

```
'aoColumns': [{ "sType": 'date' }, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: You're right on the positioning of the object, I missed that in my answer. From looking at the example code on the plugin page, I think the plugin is expecting 'property_name' in aoColumns, but 'property_name-asc' and 'property_name-desc' in the sort functions.